# Canary release when Queues are involved

Tags: deployment

[Fowler says](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html) a small percentage of traffic is routed to the Canary version while the old version is still running.

This is assuming that the routing can be controlled at the Load balancer/router level.

We have a use case where a micro-service consumes off a queue and does some processing. We were wondering how the routing can be controlled to direct a subset of traffic to the canary consumer.

One of the options we considered is to have a separate "Canary queue" but the problem is that the producers now have to be aware of this queue which sounds like a smell.

This seems like a common problem where queues are involved. Any ideas on how Canary was adopted for such applications?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785133/canary-release-when-queues-are-involved

Answer (score 0):

The more important question for you to address is how you deal with a worker which dies while processing an item from the queue.

While one worker is processing an item you usually don't want it to still be in the queue for other workers to process. On the other hand if the item is removed from the queue and only the worker knows of the item being processed, then that information will be lost if the worker crashes.

It is also tricky to know if a worker has crashed. Often a timeout may be used as a good enough approximation as to whether a worker has crashed. But how many workers are you going to allow to try processing that item. If you have a data-dependent bug there is a risk that retrying on a different worker will just cause the next worker to die. If you don't take this into account all of your workers could crash. On the other hand if a worker crashed due to a hardware failure you probably don't want to lose the item it was processing at the time.

If you have addressed all of the above already, then you have addressed most of the risks associated with the canary. At that point you might decide to simply let the canary behave like any other worker.

There is however also the potential risk of the new version outputting corrupted data. If the processing is otherwise deterministic, then you could allow the old version and the canary to both process the same input and compare the outputs. How to implement that depends on your overall system design, in some systems the solution might be to have the workers insert a small percentage of already processed items into a canary queue where your canaries can do the same processing again and you can compare the results.

Comment: How do we make sure that a canary worker gets the canary payload? Are you suggesting there should be a "canary" queue? If you are, now the producer (which is a different micro-service) needs to know about this canary queue which doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches for canary deployment with queue workers i.e using:

1. A dedicated canary queue
2. A common queue for canary and non-canary workers

Both these approaches come with their own pros and cons which are covered in detail here: http://www.varlog.co.in/blog/canary-deployment-workers/